# Is there a mechanism to signal the workflow immediately about the failure/time-out of an asynchronous activity

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

We want to implement a use-case using cadence-workflow where we want to trigger a long-running asynchronous activity and then proceed with the execution of other activities. If in the meantime, for some reason that long-running activity is failed/timed-out, we would like to stop execution of the workflow and trigger compensation activities.

Answer (score 1):

When an activity is invoked asynchronously it returns its result as Future (in Go SDK) or Promise (in Java SDK). Then the rest of the workflow can proceed without waiting on the result. The result can be used to cancel the other part of the workflow code when the activity fails or times out. When cancelled the code can execute whatever cleanup logic necessary. The concrete implementation depends on which SDK you are using.

Comment: Thanks, Maxim. I'm looking whether it is possible to signal the workflow immediately about the asynchronous activity failure without checking for the result explicitly (as it is supposed to be long-running and workflow needs to execute other activities in the meantime).

Our use-case is we want to perform some action on a resource by locking it. We can take a lock only for few seconds. So, we have to increase the lock time periodically. We are planning to use an asynchronous activity which will increase the lock-time in the background while we are executing the operations.

Comment: In this case just use activity heartbeat. It is exactly designed for this purpose of extending activity execution time periodically.

Comment: Okay. If I understand correctly, whenever an activity misses heart-beat workflow will be signalled about it immediately. Is there any example ?

Comment: Workflow will get an activity timeout error/exception and can handle it according to its business logic.